# Android deep-link to a Service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, deep-linking

I can get deep linking into an Activity working, but I'm having trouble figuring it out when trying to open a service. From what I've seen, the intent filter for a deep link requires the action `ACTION_VIEW` to work, which is an Activity Action.

The idea is to have one central Service in the app to handle all deep links, and that service can then start the right Activity depending on the data parameters.

Is this possible, or do I need to put a separate intent-filter with a different path-prefix in each activity that can be linked to?

Answer (score 5):

Android's deep linking functionality is available to foreground activities only ([ref](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)).

**Possible Solution**

You could start an `Activity` (transparent/noHistory/excludeFromRecents/singleInstance) which calls the `Service` (or the desired activities).